# Symplectic Koopmanism

Tags: sg.symplectic-geometry, ergodic-theory, operator-theory

Let $(M, \omega)$ be a $2n$-dimensional symplectic manifold and let $L_2(M,|\omega^n|)$ be the Hilbert space of complex-valued functions on $M$ that are square integrable with respect to the Liouville measure.

A classical (but still wonderful) remark due to Koopman is that given a measure preserving map $\phi: M \rightarrow M$, the operator
$$
U_\phi : L_2(M,|\omega^n|) \longrightarrow L_2(M,|\omega^n|)
$$
defined by $f \mapsto f \circ \phi$ is unitary. The operator $U_\phi$ is sometimes called the Koopman operator of the map $\phi$. Since symplectomorphisms are measure preserving, it seems natural to ask the following

**Vague question.** *Is there anything at all particular about Koopman operators of symplectomorphisms?*

Comment: Assuming that by "uniform closure", you mean "norm closure", then operators that you describe form a closed discrete set (any tow of them have distance 2).

Comment: Of course !! It was a dumb way to try to make precise a vague question. I'm editing the question to leave it vague. ;-)

Comment: What is the motivation for your question?

Comment: @AndréHenriques: I'm trying to see if there is any symplectic version of ergodic theory, one that uses that the maps are not just measure preserving.

Comment: Which results/concepts in ergodic theory do you expect to be affected by the fact that the transformation is a symplectomorphism?

Comment: How much ergodic theory do you know? An "elementary" example of what questions come up is the one I posed some time ago on Poincare recurrence. The link is in the "related questions".

Answer (score 2):

The Koopman operator is bracket preserving with respect to the canonical Poisson bracket on $C^{\infty}(M)$.  Formally, this implies the dual operator (the Frobenius-Perron operator) is a Poisson automorphism with respect to the Lie-Poisson structure on $\bigwedge^{2n}(M)$.

Comment: Thanks. This is the usual "functional" description of symplectic maps, but how to "marry" this with ergodic theory? Perhaps we have to change the space of square integrable functions for a Sobolev space and have the Koopman operator act on it instead.